# Suppose $f\leq g,h$. If $\{ f<g\} \cap \{ f < h \} = \emptyset$, then $\{f<g \} \cap \overline{\{f < h\}} = \emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology, functions

Suppose $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space. Assume that $f,g:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions such that $f \leq g$. Denote $\{f< g \}=\{ x \in X: f(x)<g(x) \}$.

Lemma: Suppose $f\leq g,h$. If $\{ f<g\} \cap \{ f < h \} = \emptyset$, then $\{f<g \} \cap \overline{\{f < h\}} = \emptyset$.

How to show the lemma above? I suppose $x \in \{ f < g\} \cap \overline{\{f<h \}}$. Then we have $f(x)<g(x)$ and $f(x)=h(x)$. Since $\{ f<g \} \cap \{f < h\} = \emptyset$, we have $f(y)=h(y)$ for all $y \in \{f < g \}$. Then I have no idea how to continue from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess what, you don't even need $X$ to be Hausdorff or for $h$ to be continuous!

**Proof:**

Start by observing that the set $\{f<g\}$ is open. Indeed, if $f(x)<g(x)$ then we may choose disjoint neighborhoods $U\ni f(x)$ and $V\ni g(x)$ (since $\mathbb R$ is Hausdorff). Then $f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$ is an open set (since $f,g$ are continuous) contained in $\{f<g\}$, which serves as an open neighborhood for $x$. Thus every point of $\{f<g\}$ has an open neighborhood, so $\{f<g\}$ is open.

Consequently, the set $\{f<g\}^c$ is closed. We are given that $\{f<h\}\subset \{f<g\}^c$, so taking closures yields $$\overline{\{f<h\}}\subset \overline{\{f<g\}^c}=\{f<g\}^c,$$
since this set is closed. Therefore $\{f<g\}$ is disjoint from $\overline{\{f<h\}}$, which is what we were trying to show.

Comment: Clear explanation.